# Passing variable into xpath selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is the code that I am using trying to pass a variable into the xpath.

```
def findcase(year):     
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear'))
    select.select_by_value(str(year))
```

Getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackboland/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Python/Selenium/8thDistBriefScraping_FUNCTIONVersion.py", line 27, in <module>
    findcase('2013','100604')
  File "/Users/jackboland/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Python/Selenium/8thDistBriefScraping_FUNCTIONVersion.py", line 18, in findcase
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear'))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 353, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)
```

I have tried the string in quotes (double and single) I have tried inserting the variable with a str(variable).  Nothing doin'  Cannot get the function to permit the passing in of a variable.

This is the relevant HTML.  But, note that when I pass in an actual number, a year, the above code works perfectly.  It only fails when trying to pass in a variable for that number.

```
//*[@id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear"]
```

Comment: The error said it fail to find the element which id is `SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear`,  please manually check the locator `#SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear` in Chrome DevTool and share related HTML in your question

Comment: Can u share HTML

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with passing variable into XPath because: 1) You're not using XPath, 2) Exception raised on line preceding to `select.select_by_value(str(year))`. Make sure that `select` node is not generated dynamically, it's not located inside `iframe`

Comment: This below is I think the relevant HTML.  One note, I am NOT getting any error if I simply enter a year into the above code instead of a variable attempts I have made.  So, the selenium code works perfectly with actual values, just fails as above trying to pass a variable name into the code.  [link] #SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear [link]

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  The code that works is below:

```
year = 2014
yearstr = str(year)
casenum = 100604
casenumstr = str(casenum)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_ddlCaseYear'))
select.select_by_value(yearstr)
#inserts the case number in that box below the year
driver.find_element_by_id('SheetContentPlaceHolder_coaCaseSearch_txtCaseNum').send_keys(casenumstr)
```